# Where are our missing posts? Site URLs show more posts than SEDE knows about, including deletions

Tags: discussion, post-id

Somebody noticed that our site has just passed [100,000 posts](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5690/28).  The total we can count on the site (questions and answers, including deleted) comes up about 9k short, and a SEDE query for all post types (which includes tag wikis and other things besides questions and answers) came up with 91,817 posts.  Post #100,000 [definitely exists](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/100000/revisions), though.

What kinds of posts can consume ID numbers other than the ones reported in the Posts table in SEDE?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh, but there is a giant flaw in the logic in that **not all ID numbers actually get used**. SQL Server reserves blocks of ID numbers which all get discarded if the server is ever restarted. Many sites have [blocks of ID numbers that never got used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267941) because of this. Using the ID number as a determinant for how many posts have ever existed will never be an accurate measurement.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that SQL Server did that.  (Or any other database, for that matter.)  Thanks.

Comment: Does it do the same thing with usernumbers?

Comment: @Catija All ID numbers which auto-increment would suffer from this.