How are question ids assigned?
When I am looking through a list of questions on a Stack Exchange Network, I noticed that the questions are assigned "ids". How is this process done and why does one id from say StackOverflow, work from another (e.g. here at meta)? I just assumed there is a random number generator built into the website. Is this correct?

Fun fact: This question is meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405173 : If change the site, i.e. keeping the same ID then stackoverflow.com/questions/405173 link end up at a answer rather than question.

Every post (question or answer) gets the next ID, which are assigned in order of when they were created.

Umm, in order?!

related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267921/what-are-these-mysterious-gaps-in-the-progression-of-post-id and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304559/where-are-our-missing-posts-site-urls-show-more-posts-than-sede-knows-about-in

@security_paranoid yes, the first post gets the ID of 1, the second post ID of 2, etc. (that is the meaning of order, in that context.)

@ShadowWizard yes, I know, but thanks. My comment was rhetorical as I thought “in order” was rather obvious. :D

@security_paranoid ah, but it's really not obvious, many things in SE aren't done in order e.g. most obvious example is the sort of answers: with the accepted first (by default), answer with -100 score might be first, then answer with +200 the second. ;) (So also in databases, many times GUID is used as primary key, then if SE would use it, post ID won't be in any order.)
